# .map returning string in array instead of array of numbers

Tags: javascript, spread-syntax

Playing around with some code I found and the results do not make sense to me.

I do not understand why the REPL thinks the array is one long string value.. I have done nothing to indicate this is a string and I am wondering why the console is giving me the following result.

```
F = (...x) => x.map(v => x+1)

//ACTUAL
F([1,2,3]) //["1,2,31"]

//EXPECTED
F([1,2,3]) //[2,3,4]
```

```js
var F =(...x) => x.map(v => x+1)  
var result = F([1,2,3]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Please create an [mcve].  What you've shown is conceptual, let's see an actual working example.

Comment: `x.map(v => x+1)`: `x` is the array, `v` the current element, hence `x+1` should be `v+1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making two mistakes.

- You are using Rest Parameters but you are passing an array.
- You are adding to `x` which is array and will be converted to `string` by usage of `+`. You return `v+1`

```js
const F=(x) => x.map(v => v+1)
console.log(F([1,2,3]))
```

If you want to use Rest Parameters then simply pass `1`,`2`,`3` as separate arguments.

```js
const F=(...x) => x.map(v => v+1)
console.log(F(1,2,3))
```

Answer (score 3):

You are passing an array as an argument since you are using [Rest  parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) for function parameter the value of `x` would become `[[1,2,3]]`. Now when you are using map, on first iteration `v` would be `[1,2,3]` and `[1,2,3] + 1` would result in string concatenation since `[1,2,3]` is not a number and while `[1,2,3]` coverts to a string it results a string with comma separated value.

So either pass arguments as multiple or use a simple parameter.

Like :

```
function F(x){ return  x.map(v => x+1) }
```

or call function like:

```
F(1, 2, 3)
// or
F(...[1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `F = x => x.map(v => v+1)`, thus...

```
F([1,2,3]) == [2, 3, 4] # evaluates to true
```

There's no need for the spread syntax. The function `F` should just accept an array so that it returns the result of `[1,2,3].map(v => v+1)`. You had `x.map(v => x+1)` which is not using the `v` parameter of the function being passed into the `.map()` function.